# Sorting an NSDictionary by Strings as days of the week

Tags: ios, nsdictionary

I have an NSDictionary as a TableViewDataSource.  I want to show Sunday-Saturday as the keys, and for the value to be 0 or 1 if it's checked or unchecked.  How do I go about sorting Sunday - Saturday since it's not a straight alphabetical order sort?

Or is there a better data structure I should be using for this?  Thanks.

Comment: I would just use integers to represent the days of the week (ie. 0 - Sunday, 1 - Monday) and wrap them in NSNumber for easy sort. Then you can just map them back to the days of the week when you display them.

Comment: @rocky ahhh that makes sense.  Can you put that as an answer so I can mark the question as complete.  Thx.

Comment: In a similar vein, you can define an enum for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use integers to represent the days of the week (ie. 0 - Sunday, 1 - Monday) and wrap them in NSNumber for easy sort. Then you can just map them back to the days of the week when you display them.